# 3d Region growing segmentation

Tags: image, image-processing, vtk, image-segmentation, itk

I am trying to do segmentation of fibrous objects within 3d-data using itk and vtk.
Is region growing applicable to this task.
My main problem are junctions. If two fibers touch each other (only slightly), the RG cant separate them.
Are there any useful pre-processing methods for this problem?
Or maybe different segmentation techniques at all?

Comment: Please post a few representative images. Methods are dependent on image characteristics.

Comment: http://imageshack.us/a/img824/4314/faser1.png

http://imageshack.us/a/img838/9360/junctionview2.png

http://imageshack.us/a/img692/6983/junctionview1.png

Comment: even if this question is quite old, did you ever find a solution for the touching regions problem?